# Unable to import .so file present in a different directory using embedded Python

Tags: python, python-c-api

I am trying to import a .so file present in a different directory as a module using embedded Python, using the code:

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    PyObject *pimport, *pimport_sys;
    pimport=PyString_FromString("moddy");
    pimport_sys=PyString_FromString("sys");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_Import(pimport_sys);
    PySys_SetPath("/XYZ/NEWFOLDER/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7"); #Absolute path
    PyImport_Import(pimport);
    PyRun_SimpleString("my=moddy.Moddy()");
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

But I always get the error `ImportError: No module named moddy`

But when I tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/XYZ/NEWFOLDER/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7")
import moddy
```

It successfully imported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PySys_SetPath has syntax error. Your path should start with / as you shown on python `/XYZ/NEWFOLDER/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7`

Comment: Sorry, made the required edit. I've used the correct syntax on my comp however.

Comment: Try recomendation from this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859538/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8859538/3710490)

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; print sys.path");` might help you debug.