# very simple code loading python module in c

Tags: python, c

I am searching a very small and simple sample to load a python module in C app. everywhere i search I see long example and I am not understand. If this is duplicate share stackoverflow link and I will delete this question. Thank you and i am new to Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Python Module name reverse.py as below:

```
def rstring(s):
    i = len(s)-1
    t = ''
    while(i > -1):
    t += s[i]
    i -= 1
    return t
```

Create a C application as below:

```
#include <Python.h>
int main()
{
    PyObject *strret, *mymod, *strfunc, *strargs;
    char *cstrret;
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetPath("."); 
    mymod = PyImport_ImportModule("reverse");
    strfunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(mymod, "rstring");
    strargs = Py_BuildValue("(s)", "Hello World");
    strret = PyEval_CallObject(strfunc, strargs);
    PyArg_Parse(strret, "s", &cstrret);
    printf("Reversed string: %s\n", cstrret);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now be sure to keep the reverse.py and your C application in the same folder. After that please compile and run C Sample Application.

Please study the each line in above sample, as there are about 20 total lines and if you have question about any line please let me know, I would be pleased to answer.

Credit goes to the SO Link here as I have corrected those samples: [Embedding Python into C - importing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283964/embedding-python-into-c-problem-importing-modules)

Comment: thanks, as simple as i was searching.